# Is there a way to check for the value in the table.insert in LUA?

Tags: lua, lua-table, fivem

So i am wrighting a script for a FiveM server and i have a question. I am kinda new to LUA so keep that in mind. As far as I understand this line of code does this, It checks if the items on the invetory are greater than 0 and then it inserts the x item. The problem is that the player can insert much more items than it has on the inventory. What i mean by that? The player has 10 chocolates but he can add 20 on the table. Is there a way to check how many items he wants to put then check his inventory and then add it to the table? Here is the lines of code that do that.

```
local elements = {}

   for i=1, #inventory.items, 1 do

     local item = inventory.items[i]

     if item.count > 0 then
       table.insert(elements, {label = item.label .. ' x' .. item.count, type = 'item_standard', value = item.name})
     end

   end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- create an empty table
local elements = {}
-- for each item in some inventory list
for i=1, #inventory.items, 1 do
  -- reference that item
  local item = inventory.items[i]
   -- I assume you can have more than one of each items so if you have at least one
   if item.count > 0 then
     -- insert a new table with info about that item into elements
     table.insert(elements, {label = item.label .. ' x' .. item.count, type = 'item_standard', value = item.name})
   end

end
```

This code does not manage any counts. The only way so this code can add more items than a player has is by running that loop more than once. It simply transfers information from one list to another.
As you're adding those items from the players inventory it is not necessary to compare their count vs his inventory